# Ayuda con un ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, método

Buenas tardes. 
Alguien me podría colaborar con los métodos del ArrayList Java - Netbeans.
Gracias quien pueda responder

Comment: Por favor, revisa la ayuda [faq] para aprender como hacer preguntas adecuadamente. Y consulta las preguntas ya respondidas para ver si resuelven tu duda.